# I got issue in strcpy in C, is there any mistake in my code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char oldS[] = "Hello";
    char newS[] = "Bye";
    strcpy(newS, oldS);
    puts(newS);
}
```

I was trying to learn `string.h` in C, will doing `strcpy` I am unable to get the output.
output is like

```
koushik@Koushiks-MacBook-Air C % cd "/Users/koushik/Documents/
C/" && gcc stringcopy.c -o stringcopy && "/Users/koushik/Docum
ents/C/"stringcopy
zsh: illegal hardware instruction "/Users/koushik/Documents/C/"stringcopy
```

Comment: Hint: `char newS[] = "Bye";` is the same as `char newS[4] = "Bye";`

Comment: @koushik `newS[]` has room for 3 characters and a _null character_.  What does `"Hello"` need?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `strcpy()`, the size of the destination string should be large enough to store the copied string. Otherwise, it may result in undefined behavior.

As you've declared the char array without specifying the size, it was initialized with the size of the string "Bye", which is smaller than the string "Hello". That's why problem occurred.

Solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() 
{
    char oldS[6] = "Hello";
    char newS[6] = "Bye";
    strcpy(newS, oldS);
    puts(newS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space to use strcpy either way with creating an array with a suffisent size or using **malloc**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).